# Can i have group_vars used in Jijnja2 template?

Tags: automation, ansible, jinja2

I have the following variable that i want to use in Jinja2 template and i am not sure if it is even possible

```
tag: pony
```

This is how I tried using it:

```
{% if ansible_fqdn  in groups['machines-{{ tag }}'] %}
{% for host in groups['machines-{{ tag }}'] %}
echo "Do some magic with my {{ tag }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible ? And how of course :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
{% set group = 'machine-' + tag %}

{% if ansible_fqdn  in groups[group] %}
{% for host in groups[group] %}
echo "Do some magic with my {{ tag }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```